# spring boot - ControllerAdvice use to service layer

Tags: spring, exception, spring-data-jpa

I know that for all the controllers from spring one Global ControllerAdvice can work.

But in my case if any common exception is occurring like not records on the db to pagination which is written in service layer, then how to deal with this and use the Global ControllerAdvice.

Hope this would not be silly question to ask.

Comment: you can throw exception from service class also and it will be caught by `ControllerAdvice`

Comment: Thanks let me try that.